# Why Aren't These Errors Rendering For Nested Associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a MediaItem model that has two `has_one` associations. I validate that one or the other are present using:

```
validates_presence_of :photo, allow_nil: true
validates_presence_of :video, allow_nil: true
validate :photo_or_video_present  

 def photo_or_video_present
   if !(photo.blank? ^ video.blank?)
     errors['photo_attributes.image'] << 'Select a photo or a video'
     errors['video_attributes.uid'] << 'Select a photo or a video'
   end
 end
```

Which gives me the following error object when the form is rendered:

```
<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f99c8a71fc0 
    @base=#<MediaItem id: nil,
                   title: "asdadasdasd", 
                    slug: "asdadasdasd", 
              gallery_id: 1, 
              created_at: nil, 
              updated_at: nil>, 
    @messages={:"photo_attributes.image"=>["Select a photo or a video"],          
               :"video_attributes.uid"=>["Select a photo or a video"], 
               :title=>[] }>
```

However these errors don't show up in the nested models. The form looks like this:

```
<div class="FormWrapper">
  <%= simple_form_for [:admin, @gallery, @media_item], html: { class: "#{action_name.titleize}PhotoForm" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>


    <div class="PhotoInputs">
      <h3>Photo</h3>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :photo do |ff|  %>
        <%= ff.input :image, as: :file_upload, input_html: {preview: @media_item.photo.image} %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="VideoInputs">
      <h3>Video</h3>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :video do |ff|  %>
        <%= ff.input :provider, as: :radio_buttons, collection: Video::PROVIDERS %>
        <%= ff.input :uid %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/form_submit', locals: {resource: @media_item}  %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Why are these inline errors failing to show up?**

*Note: There is no absolutely no problem with the functioning of the form. I can create and edit both model and nested model without issue.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 validations do nothing `validates_presence_of :photo, allow_nil: true` `validates_presence_of :video, allow_nil: true` because you are validating the presence but allowing it to not be present. I would just add the `error` to `:base` and render that in the view. e.g.

```
validates :has_photo_or_video

def has_photo_or_video 
  if (photo.blank? ^ video.blank?)
    errors.add(:base,"Please select a photo or video")
  end
end
```

Then in the view

```
<% f.errors[:base].each do |message| %>
   <span>message</span>
<% end %>
```

I have not seen an implementation of inline errors like you describe although you could try something like this as well:

```
def has_photo_or_video 
  if !(photo.blank? ^ video.blank?)
    photo.errors.add(:image,"Please select a photo or video")
    video.errors.add(:uid,"Please select a photo or video")
  end
end
```

Although I make no representation as to whether or not this will work.

Your issue is that it is looking for your errors to be contained in a nested hash like

```
{photo_attributes: {image: ["Please select a photo or video"]}, 
 video_attributes: {uid: ["Please select a photo or video"]} }
```

The only way I have seen this done is by validating on the associated model which is not possible in your case since it is a one or both type procedure. At least as I understand it.

If this is an either or type procedure meaning a `MediaItem` is either a `Photo` **or** a `Video` but **not both** then I would suggest looking into polymorphism as it would make this procedure far easier.

Or even better still scrap `MediaItem` all together and add the `title` attribute to `Photo` and `Video` and then create each one separately as this seems like the easiest route. (You could still define a method for `media_items` that would grab all of these)

Comment: Thanks. I've actually greatly simplified MediaItem for this example. It has a lot of other functionality that is shared across both video and photo, and ties in to other models in ways that make polymorphism a poor choice. As far as the inline errors go, Simple form gives me inline errors out-of-the-box for all MediaItem errors related to those properties, so when you say you haven't seen an implementation of inline errors as I describe are you specifically talking about inline errors on nested models?

Comment: @Pedr yes I have seen inline errors like this implemented but only when the validations are preformed on the nested model not the parent. Since you cannot perform validations on the nested model because of your design I am not sure the best way to go about this other than base errors.